# Split, aggregate and combine matrix and keep the same structure in base R

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate

I have a matrix with a grouping column and a column to sum up values.

I want to **split** the matrix into groups, **sum** up some values (by keeping the same length of vectors), **unsplit** it and **assign** them to a new column?

*What is the most performant and base-R-onic way of doing that?*

The winner for now is an `lapply` function, but I am wondering if there is another function I am missing? Something like `stats::aggregate` which keeps the same structure?

I would like to stay in base R and keep matrices, so no `dplyr` or `data.table` ;).

**Edit1:** I included the aggregate + merge and the sapply solution powered by @IceCreamToucan. (Thanks for that). Its not a very fair comparison for `aggregate` as I first convert to data.frames and then back to matrices.

**Edit2:** With bigger matrices and 100 groups `ave` outperforms the other functions. Thanks to @Gregor for this one.

```
set.seed(104)
smpl = sample(1:100, size = 10000, T)
mat0 <- as.matrix(data.frame(
  group=smpl,
  sum=sample(seq(0,100,10), length(smpl), T)
))
mat1 <- cbind(mat0, "sums"=0)


library(microbenchmark)
check <- function(values) {
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) all.equal(values[[1]], x)))}
mf = microbenchmark(#check = check,
                    forloop = {
                      mat <- mat1
                      for (z in unique(mat[,'group'])) {
                        mat[mat[,'group'] == z,'sums'] = sum(mat[mat[,'group'] == z,'sum'])
                      }
                      mat
                    },
                    lapply = {
                      mat <- mat1
                      mat[,'sums'] <- unlist(lapply(unique(mat[,'group']), function(i) {
                        sums = sum(mat[mat[,'group'] == i,'sum'])
                        rep(sums, length(mat[mat[,'group'] == i,'sum']))
                      }))
                      mat
                    },
                    sapply = {
                      mat <- mat1
                      mat <- mat[order(mat[,'group']),]
                      mat[,'sums'] <- rep(sapply(split(mat[, 'sum'], mat[, 'group']), sum), 
                                          table(mat[, 'group']))
                      mat
                    },
                    ave = {
                      mat <- mat1
                      mat[,'sums'] <- ave(x = mat[, 'sum'], mat[, 'group'], FUN = sum)
                      mat[order(mat[,'group']),]
                    },
                    aggregate = {
                      matA <- mat0
                      matA <- matA[order(matA[,'group']),]
                      res = aggregate(sum ~ group, FUN = sum, data = matA)
                      matdf = data.frame(matA)
                      base::merge(res, matdf, by ="group")
                    }
)
mf
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
>    forloop 19.94083 25.73131 25.95823 25.97898 26.58043  38.68300   100  bc
>     lapply 15.96057 21.44226 24.23693 21.88130 22.41287 311.00252   100  bc
>     sapply 21.89081 22.41981 23.42291 22.70492 23.04978  37.41853   100  b 
>        ave 11.79256 12.08868 12.51119 12.27613 12.52803  18.20577   100 a  
>  aggregate 26.54753 27.31484 29.09592 27.71163 28.71937  54.75284   100   c
> ```

Comment: If you were using data frames, you could `merge` `mat1` with `aggregate(sum ~ group, FUN = sum, data = mat1)`.

Comment: That works with matrices too, but it drops the values. The original matrix has nrow 8, and the `aggregate` result has nrow 4. Or do you mean the merging needs data.frames?

Comment: Yeah the `aggregate` part works, but not `merge`, which is how you would replicate the individual values.

Comment: You could get the `sums` column as `rep(sapply(split(mat[, 'sum'], mat[, 'group']), sum), table(mat[, 'group']))`. I think this is more confusing than just using data frames, but if you're married to matrices that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Thats nice, but unfortunately still slower than lapply. I'll include it in my answer and benchmark if you dont mind?

Comment: Interesting. You can incude it, sure.

Comment: `ave` is faster than for loop but still about 4-5x slower than `lapply`. `ave(x = mat1[, 'sum'], mat1[, 'group'], FUN = sum)`

Comment: ...though with the timings being in microseconds I wonder if the example is large enough to be good. If you're really worried about performance I recommend doing an example with, say, at least 100 groups with a few rows each.

Comment: I increased the matrix size, and it seems for big matrices, 'ave' is the new winner.

Comment: And `ave` is just `split` and `lapply` internally ;)

Comment: At this point, rather than editing solutins into your question, I would recommend you write up an answer.

Comment: @Gregor: Since you came up with the fastest option, I would like to credit your answer, fi you want to write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting various R-FAQ ([how to sum by group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061), [Grouping functions and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26769477/903061)), the base R function for the purpose of summing by group without aggregation is `ave`:

```
ave(x = mat1[, 'sum'], mat1[, 'group'], FUN = sum)
```

As edited into the question, `ave` is quite fast when there are lots of groups.